Java: ProcessBuilder with psql command, ProcessBuilder with kubectl port-forward, won't connect to the database. Same commands work on cmdline

Os: DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04


DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS" psql: psql (PostgreSQL) 12.20


(Ubuntu 12.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) Java: openjdk version "11.0.24"


2024-07-16 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.24+8-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu320.04) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.24+8-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu320.04, mixed mode, sharing)

If I run the following two commands on cmd line it works fine and I can retrieve data (the user in this case doesn't have a password):
kubectl port-forward service/service-name 7432:5432
psql -h localhost -p 7432 -U username -d database -w -t -c "select id from foo.bar where id='1'"

Method for port-forward I have:
public static Process portForward(String type, String deploymentName, String containerPort, String localPort) {

    Predicate<Process> readyPredicate = Objects::nonNull;
    String command = "kubectl port-forward " + type + "/" + deploymentName + " " + containerPort + ":" + localPort;
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", command);
    Process process;

    try {
        process = processBuilder.start();
        final Thread thread = new Thread(process::destroyForcibly);
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(thread);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    if (!readyPredicate.test(process)) {
        final String errorMsg = String.format("Deployment '" + deploymentName + "' was not ready");
        throw new IllegalStateException(errorMsg);
    }

    return process;
}

If I run port-forward on cmd line this is what the process looks like:

If I run port-forward through Java ProcessBuilder the process looks like this:

There's no difference between the two.
Method for psql command:
public static boolean psqlQuery() {
    final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c", "psql -h localhost -p 7432 -U username -d database -w -t -c \"select id from foo.bar where id='1'\"");

    try {
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        process.waitFor();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        List<String> output = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
        output.forEach(LOGGER::info);

        BufferedReader errorreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
        List<String> erroroutput = errorreader.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
        erroroutput.forEach(LOGGER::error);

        return output.stream().anyMatch(c -> c.contains("1"));
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

I'm running the portForward method and then the psqlQuery method after it.
This doesn't work and gives an error message saying it can't connect, but if the psqlQuery runs while I'm running the portForward from cmd line it work fine.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You need not (and should not) use bash or sh.  new ProcessBuilder("kubectl", "port-forward", type + "/" + deploymentName, containerPort + ":" + localPort) and new ProcessBuilder("psql", "-h", "localhost", "-p", "7432", "-U", "username", "-d", "database", "-w", "-t", "-c", "select id from foo.bar where id='1'") will do the job quite well.  And you should use processBuilder.inheritIO(); to allow the subprocesses’ output to show up, including any error messages.

So I actually got this to work immediately after writing this out, but I'll put this here just in case it helps someone.
The code was executing too quickly and the port-forward wasn't ready, so just adding Thread.sleep(2000) was enough to fix it.
